# What is the recommended order for watching "Barakamon" and "Handa-kun"?

Tags: barakamon, handa-kun

[*Barakamon*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/22789/Barakamon) was a highly rated Slice of Life Comedic show from Summer 2014 (Which I never got around to picking up). [*Handa-Kun*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/32648/Handa-kun) aired much more recently (Summer 2016), but is described as a prequel to the original.

Is it required that I watch *Barakamon* before watching *Handa-Kun*? Are there any references in *Handa-Kun* that may spoil *Barakamon*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: watch whichever you feel like watching.

---

You can actually watch it in any order. Having seen both of them, except for the same protagonist they don't have any link between them.

*Handa-kun* is an anime in which the protagonist is a high school student. This one leans highly towards comedy than a slice of life. But it's definitely fun to watch.

*Barakamon* is more the typical slice of life anime with bits and pieces of comedy, it has a sense of purpose unlike *Handa-kun* which is just everyday events. Here *Handa-kun* is grown-up and is trying to find some inspiration.